# Redux Form wrapper for kendo-react-ui Input error

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, kendo-react-ui

I am using react-kendo-ui. I want to wrap Input from @progress/kendo-react-inputs to use it with ReduxForm. Please find my code below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Input } from '@progress/kendo-react-inputs';

const InputText = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
    <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
            <Input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
            {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
    </div>
)

export default InputText
```

Call the InputText from another component as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Input } from '@progress/kendo-react-inputs';
import InputText from './input-text';

const validateNotEmpty = value => !value ? 'Must enter a value' : null;

const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
}

const AddLoc= ({ handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            <Field
                label="Address"
                name="address"
                component={InputText}
                validate={validateNotEmpty}
            />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
)

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'AddLoc'
})(AddLoc)
```

But while typing inside the input text it keeps giving the following error/warning:

```
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `nativeEvent` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
```

[image]

While typing inside the input text automatically outputs **[object Object]**. Please check the image above. Could anyone please let me know what is causing the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reduxForm` works only with pure DOM `<input />`. Internally it clones the elements search the children and then attaches the `onChange` dynamically. So it will not work with the `Input` and the `NumericTextBox` from the `@progress/kendo-react-inputs` package. This statement is based on the [official kendo documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-redux-form/) about integrating with the redux-form.

The same [author](https://github.com/erikras) of the `redux-form` have fork of it called [react-final-form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) which could be used on any component that have `Value` and `onChange` props. By our tests it works with the components from `@progress/kendo-react-inputs` and `@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns` packages. It looks kendo already have an example using `final-form` in their [integration section](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/integration/react-final-form-integration/).